# ConstraintLayout - center and constraint

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I want to achieve the following but I'm not sure how to do it.

As you can see in the images below:

1. I want `Box 1` and `Box 2` to be centered at all times.
2. `Box 2` should have width `wrap_content`.
3. `Box 3` can be `visible` or `gone`.

   1. When it's `visible` I want it to be to the left of `Box 2`, but constrained on the left by `Box 1`.
   2. When it's gone I want `Box 2` to be able to stretch as much as it needs but still constrained by `Box 1`

I'm open to suggestions. I was trying to achieve all this in XML but perhaps I need some code here too? Thank you all in advance.

[image: diagram 1]    [image: diagram 2]   [image: diagram 3]

Comment: I don't think this is possible in XML as you would need to constrain Box 2 BOTH to the edges of Box 1 to keep it centered and its left to Box 3 to keep it from pushing Box 3 out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want Box 1 and Box 2 to be centered at all times.

You can center Box 1 to the right and left edges of the parent, and make Box 2 edges constraints to Box 1 or also to the parent edges.

> When it's gone I want `Box 2` to be able to stretch as much as it needs but still constrained by Box 1 (The same for `Box 3`)

Then enable width constraints to `Box 2`, & `Box 3` using `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`, hence they can not exceed the limits of Box1.

Then add normal edge constraints between Box 2 & 3.

> Box 3 When it's visible I want it to be to the left of Box 2

Use a positive horizontal biasing (`app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"`) to `Box 3` so that its right edge can be biased to `Box 2`

**UPDATE**

> I still see an issue with your suggestion. When Box 2 becomes large, it pushes Box 3 away and out of its boundaries with Box 1

You can add `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` to `Box 3`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF2CC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Box1"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#D5E8D4"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Box2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/box1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/box1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#F8CECC"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Box3"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/box2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/box2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/box1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box1" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Previews:

[image]

Box 3 is constraint to the left of Box 1

[image]

Box 3 is hidden & Box 2 is constraint to the left of Box 1

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @Zain. I still see an issue with your suggestion. When `Box 2` becomes large, it pushes `Box 3` away and out of its boundaries with `Box 1`.

Comment: @JoaoSousa Please check `UPDATE` section in the answer